# C# Executing http requests in a loop where I want the result but don't want to wait before processing the next loop

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

I'm writing a method GetComputers() which takes a list of strings which are IP Addresses. From this list of strings I want to be build a list of Computer objects which will have properties IPAddress and Name. To get the Name, i need to send an http request to the address. So I want to loop through the IP Addresses list, and for each IP address send an http request using the address to get the Names. However, i want the http requests to be done in parallel. I don't want to wait for each http request to return before I start processing the next ip address. I want to know if my method to do this is correct.

Here is an extract of the code:

Computer class:

```
public class Computer 
{
   public string IPAddress {get; set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Class with GetComputers() method (I've simplified it and removed any error handling)

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    public List<Computer> GetComputers(List<string> ipAddresses)
    {
        List<Computer> computers = new List<Computer>();
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Tasks>();
        
        foreach (string ipAddress in ipAddresses)
        { 
           Computer computer = new Computer();
           computer.IPAddress = ipAddress;
           Task task = Task.Run(() => {
            computer.Name = GetName(ipAddress);
           });
           
           computers.Add(computer);
           tasks.Add(task);
        }
        
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        return computers;
    }

    private async Task<string> GetName(string ipAddress)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://" + ipAddress + "/api/name");
        string name = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        
        return name;
    }
}
```

So far this has worked for me, but I want to know if this is the proper use of Task.Run(), or if there is a better way

Answer (score 2):

As presented I'm surprised that your code compiles because `computer.Name = GetName(ipAddress);` is assigning a `Task<string>` to a `string`. Even fixing this though, your approach has some problems, and I would recommend reading about idiomatic async/await programming (where you shouldn't generally use `Task.Run`).

I would recommend something like this:

```
public async Task<List<Computer>> GetComputers(List<string> ipAddresses)
{
    var results = await Task.WhenAll(
        ipAddresses.Select(
            async ipAddress =>
            {
                return new Computer
                {
                    IPAddress = ipAddress,
                    Name = await GetName(ipAddress)
                };
            }));

    return results.ToList();
}
```

There are a few useful tricks in there. The key one is `await Task.WhenAll(things.Select(async thing => await ...))`. `Task.WhenAll` takes a collection of `Task`s, and turns it into a `Task` with the results in, so you only have to await it once.

What's actually going on under the hood is a bit involved, but essentially `Select` loops through your collection triggering `Task`s, but not waiting for them to complete, and then `await Task.WhenAll(...)` receives them and waits for them all, giving you the results at the end.

Other things to Google:

- `IEnumerable` and Linq (where `Select` comes from)
- Object initialisers (the `new Computer` syntax)
- Functional programming, if you want to avoid the kinds of bugs that you get from adding things to lists from multithreaded code. Tldr: never mutate anything and it can't go too badly wrong.